# How to create "upload image " to registration form?

Tags: wordpress, forms, registration

I'm creating a website on wordpress. I wanted to add "upload image" part and after people registered, I'll check the image and if it's true image, I'll accept the registration. Like spotify. Spotify wants student certificate to be sure and if it’s right, after that, they allow to use spotify on student price.

I know there are plugins but they aren't free. So, how can I do that for free? I searched for code or method but couldn't fide any source.

Answer (score 0):

Replace existing function

```
   function um_get_avatar_uri( $image, $attrs ) {
    $uri = false;
    $uri_common = false;
    $find = false;
    $ext = '.' . pathinfo( $image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $custom_profile_photo = get_user_meta(um_user( 'ID' ), 'profile_photo', 'true');

    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        //multisite fix for old customers
        $multisite_fix_dir = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir();
        $multisite_fix_url = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_url();
        $multisite_fix_dir = str_replace( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sites' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . get_current_blog_id() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $multisite_fix_dir );
        $multisite_fix_url = str_replace( '/sites/' . get_current_blog_id() . '/', '/', $multisite_fix_url );


        if ( $attrs == 'original' && file_exists( $multisite_fix_dir . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo{$ext}" ) ) {
            $uri_common = $multisite_fix_url . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo{$ext}";        
        } elseif ( file_exists( $multisite_fix_dir . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo-{$attrs}x{$attrs}{$ext}" ) ) {
            $uri_common = $multisite_fix_url . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo-{$attrs}x{$attrs}{$ext}";
        } elseif ( file_exists( $multisite_fix_dir . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo-{$attrs}{$ext}" ) ) {
            $uri_common = $multisite_fix_url . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo-{$attrs}{$ext}";
        } else {
            $sizes = UM()->options()->get( 'photo_thumb_sizes' );
            if ( is_array( $sizes ) ) {
                $find = um_closest_num( $sizes, $attrs );
            }

            if ( file_exists( $multisite_fix_dir . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo-{$find}x{$find}{$ext}" ) ) {
                $uri_common = $multisite_fix_url . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo-{$find}x{$find}{$ext}";
            } elseif ( file_exists( $multisite_fix_dir . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo-{$find}{$ext}" ) ) {
                $uri_common = $multisite_fix_url . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo-{$find}{$ext}";
            } elseif ( file_exists( $multisite_fix_dir . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo{$ext}" ) ) {
                $uri_common = $multisite_fix_url . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo{$ext}";
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $attrs == 'original' && file_exists( UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir() . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo{$ext}" ) ) {
        $uri = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir()  . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo{$ext}";
    } elseif ( file_exists( UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir() . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $custom_profile_photo ) ) {
        $uri = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_url() . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $custom_profile_photo;     
    } elseif ( file_exists( UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir() . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo-{$attrs}x{$attrs}{$ext}" ) ) {
        $uri = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_url() . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo-{$attrs}x{$attrs}{$ext}";
    } elseif ( file_exists( UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir() . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo-{$attrs}{$ext}" ) ) {
        $uri = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_url() . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo-{$attrs}{$ext}";
    } else {
        $sizes = UM()->options()->get( 'photo_thumb_sizes' );
        if ( is_array( $sizes ) ) {
            $find = um_closest_num( $sizes, $attrs );
        }

        if ( file_exists( UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir() . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo-{$find}x{$find}{$ext}" ) ) {
            $uri = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_url() . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo-{$find}x{$find}{$ext}";
        } elseif ( file_exists( UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir() . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo-{$find}{$ext}" ) ) {
            $uri = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_url() . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo-{$find}{$ext}";
        } elseif ( file_exists( UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_dir() . um_user( 'ID' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "profile_photo{$ext}" ) ) {
            $uri = UM()->uploader()->get_upload_base_url() . um_user( 'ID' ) . "/profile_photo{$ext}";
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $uri_common ) && empty( $uri ) ) {
        $uri = $uri_common;
    }

    $cache_time = apply_filters( 'um_filter_avatar_cache_time', current_time( 'timestamp' ), um_user( 'ID' ) );
    if ( ! empty( $cache_time ) ) {
        $uri .= "?{$cache_time}";
    }

    return $uri;
}
```

Comment: where to? Isn't it php code? Bc I did it but it didn't work?

Comment: /core/um-short-functions.php